# Scala filter a list based on a max value

Tags: mongodb, scala

I have the following MAP:

```
[
  { "animal": "dog", "age": 1},
  { "animal": "dog", "age": 2},
  { "animal": "dog", "age": 3},
  { "animal": "cat", "age": 1},
  { "animal": "cat", "age": 4},
  { "animal": "rabbit", "age": 9}
]
```

How do I return a result so that I get both dogs, cats and rabbits with the max age. Example:

```
[
    { "animal": "dog", "age": 3},    # oldest dog in DB
    { "animal": "cat", "age": 4},    # oldest cat in DB
    { "animal": "rabbit", "age": 9}  # oldest rabbit in DB

]
```

I am trying to get this using two scala .map() aggregation but no success so far.

Comment: What is the type of the list? `List[JsValue]`? `List[SomeCustomType]`?

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco It's `Future[List[BSONDocument]]` which is a result from MongoDB

Comment: You could write a mongodb query which only returns the oldest animals: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/

Comment: @soote: Yes I tried that first but that return a complex looking JSON back and its even more not-so-obvious to display all other fields other than animal name and their age

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a case class like `case class Pet(animal: String, age: Int)`:

```
list.groupBy(_.animal).values.map(_.maxBy(_.age)).toList
```

For `List[BSONDocument]`, same concept:

```
list.groupBy(_.getAs[String]("animal")).values.map(_.maxBy(_.getAs[Int]("age"))).toList
```

Comment: `list.groupBy(_.animal).mapValues(_.maxBy(_.age))...` ?

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco: Can this be done without using case classes?